# How is reputation calculated?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Is it calculated on the fly every time a reputation score needs to be displayed, or is every user's reputation stored as an integer in the database and updated as necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that a user has a Rep Score that is updated any time something happens which changes rep.

Your rep can be totally recalculated using a mechanism that moderators have. This will go through everything available and give you a brand spanking new (and as accurate as possible) rep score.

Answer (score 4):

I believe a running total is stored. The administrators can force a rep-recalc (which wouldn't need to be done if it was always calculated on the fly)

Comment: That's already been done before. Skeet Overflow comes to mind.

Comment: Huh               ?